# Sparkpost SMTP: emails not being delivered to 0:mtccc-com.mail.protection.outlook.com

Tags: email, outlook

I have been hitting my head over this issue for 3 years now.

We are a small ecommerce store using Sparkpost API to send email.

We have problems sending email to outlook / hotmail / Microsoft365 mail based email addresses.

Their DNS MX record is:
0:mtccc-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
5:mail.messaging.microsoft.com

- We have correct SFP, DKIM, DMARC setup
- Not on any known blacklists
- Dedicated IP address
- We applied and are on SNDS and JMRP programs
- Emails are marked as transactional

But our emails are still landing into spam or don't get delivered to the customer.

Only way to send the customer an email is from Gmail based on the same domain.

So I assume this has something to do with Sparkpost IP or headers they attach.

Any ideas how we can resolve this?

Sparkpost has not been helpful. They are just saying to send more volume(which is not possible for a small store) and look at email templates (which I'm in process of simplifying).

Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft is notorious for not delivering mail, dropping it on the floor without notice to either sender or recipient. You're _fortunate_ if one gets into spam. This has been going on for years without MS doing much of anything to improve the situation. At this point I have to advise anyone using their services that they are guaranteed to lose mail.

Comment: You have to investigate further. Microsoft have some way to inferface with so you can understand:  Junk Mail Reporting Program (JMRP) https://postmaster.live.com/snds/JMRP.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 - Smart Network Data Services program (SNDS)  http://postmaster.msn.com/snds/ - Sender Score Certified Mail program https://senderscore.org/ - and finally their guide : http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/3/3/e3397e7c-17a6-497d-9693-78f80be272fb/enhance_deliver.pdf

Comment: @MichaelHampton thats my plan, if they have 0 response to my emails and phone calls (yes I'm planning to call them) I will point every customer with those MX records to page with "Why you should stop using Office365 email" title.

Comment: @maudam I have applied for both of those programs and have not received any reports back about email going to spam. So I am confused why this is still happening without report being sent back. As far as a guideline - its not possible in 2019 to abide by those guidelines, they were probably written before 2010 - email has evolved since.

Comment: All the mails sent to Outlook not received or only part？Microsoft has a lot of mechanisms to detect spam. And I think it's better to contact Microsoft for more professional help.